# One hot encoding - data stored in a 1d array

Tags: python, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I have a 1-dimensional array which I am using to store a categorical feature of my dataset like so: (where each data instance belongs to many categories and the categories are separated by commas)

```
Administration   Oral ,Aged ,Area Under Curve ,Cholinergic Antagonists/adverse effects/*pharmacokinetics/therapeutic use ,Circadian Rhythm/physiology ,Cross-Over Studies ,Delayed-Action Preparations ,Dose-Response Relationship   Drug ,Drug Administration Schedule ,Female ,Humans ,Mandelic Acids/adverse effects/blood/*pharmacokinetics/therapeutic use ,Metabolic Clearance Rate ,Middle Aged ,Urinary Incontinence/drug therapy ,Xerostomia/chemically induced ,

Adult ,Anti-Ulcer Agents/metabolism ,Antihypertensive Agents/metabolism ,Benzhydryl Compounds/administration & dosage/blood/*pharmacology ,Caffeine/*metabolism ,Central Nervous System Stimulants/metabolism ,Cresols/administration & dosage/blood/*pharmacology ,Cross-Over Studies ,Cytochromes/*pharmacology ,Debrisoquin/*metabolism ,Drug Interactions ,Humans ,Male ,Muscarinic Antagonists/pharmacology ,Omeprazole/*metabolism ,*Phenylpropanolamine ,Polymorphism   Genetic ,Tolterodine Tartrate ,Urinary Bladder Diseases/drug therapy ,
...
...
```

Each element of the array represents the categories a data instance belongs to. I need to use one-hot encoding, so I can use these as a feature to train my algorithm. I understand this can be achieved using scrikit-learn, however I am unsure how to implement it. (There are ~150 possible categories and around 1,000 data instances.)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use the [get_dummies](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) method in pandas for this. The interface is a little nicer especially if you're already using pandas to store your data. The sklearn implementations are a bit more involved. If you do decide to go the sklearn route you will either need to use [OneHotEncoder](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#encoding-categorical-features) or [LabelBinarizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing_targets.html#preprocessing-targets). Both would require you to first convert your categories to integer values which you can accomplish with [LabelEncoder](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing_targets.html#label-encoding).